Microstrategy - security filter to filter automatically base on user
looking to use the security filter but i see i big big caveat which is about the filter security object itself.  let say i have 500 users in whic need to only see there own data.  Simple , correct ? The only way that i seem to make this possible is by having to create 500 security filter to hardcoded the condition one by one for each.  That make no sense.
Note 1: Each user no the ability to see only there data.  Not a group of user.
Note 2: Of course my table contain the user attributes.  Let say table SALES : LOGIN_ACCOUNT, DEPARTMENT, SALES_YEARS
Note 3 : I cannot use the PROMPT option like microstrategy seem to allow.  Of course would be a BIG security hole making possible to any user A prompt data for USER B.
Base on Microstrategy text "Using Database Tables That Contain Security Information
If your organization maintains security information in database tables, you can use a system prompt to build MicroStrategy security mechanisms using the database security tables. For example, you can restrict the data returned based on a user's login by creating a report filter that accesses columns in your security tables and includes the User Login system prompt. You can also restrict data access based on two or more unrelated attributes by using logical views (database views) and the User Login system prompt in a security filter."
Note 4 : I do not want to create a special script to create 500 security objects automatically...that become infernal to manage...
Please help !
We did try in the pass using an automatic job in which create security object for all possibility user...but that become a extreme complicated program

There's system prompts you can use, if you haven't had a look at them: https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB10937-what-is-the-feature-System-Prompt?language=en_US
That's about the only thing I can think of besides coding those security filters. But that shouldn't be too problematic iff you've got a tight handle on those usernames etc.

How about you maintain the user securities in a separate table -
user_security_table:
userID --> self explanatory
data_column --> For identifying the user's entitlement

You can then bring in this table in MSTR and join it with your other reporting tables.
And then you'll have to add a filter --> userID attribute = "Login ID" system prompt.
This prompt is usually availbale in Public Objects/Prompts/System Prompts/Login ID.
Something like this -
from fact_table a11
join user_security_table a12
on (a11.data_column = a12.data_column)
where a12.userid = <login ID>

This way, you can achieve the same row level security without using a single MSTR Security Filter.

Really appreciate answer.  Actually, we have continue looking for solution.  And while this solution using tables with security is also a good solution.  There is a main blocker to use either SYSTEM LOGIN with security filter OR using Tables with security.  We realize that because we like all this using Intelligent CUBE, that make mandatory to put the cube at lowest level, in those case at login employee level.  Because CUBE is build not in reel time, it need that lowest level.  Which we cannot have . This is where the normal SECURITY FILTER come into help to a price a management complexity.

creating security filters is no longer a big deal in Mstr. you can use mstrio python library and code whatever logic you want. Smth like below will work
for i in range(0,len(userlist[:,0])):

  QUALIFICATION = Expression(
        tree=AttributeFormPredicate(
            function=Function.EQUALS,

            parameters=[
                ConstantParameter(constant=Variant(type=VariantType.STRING, value=YOURVALUE))
               
            ],
             attribute=SchemaObjectReference(
                 sub_type=ObjectSubType.ATTRIBUTE, object_id='YOURATTRID', name='YOURATTRNAME'
             ),
             form=SchemaObjectReference(
                 sub_type=ObjectSubType.ATTRIBUTE_FORM_SYSTEM,
                 name = 'YOURATTRFORMNAME'
             )
        )
    )
    folder_id = 'YOURFOLDERID'
   new_security_filter = SecurityFilter.create(
        connection = mstrconn,
        qualification=QUALIFICATION,
        name = str(userlist[i,0]),
        destination_folder=folder_id

    )


Thanks.  That's a old thread but who knows, can help someone.
